# How to create dynamic menu with list items?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a menu using list item's and unordered list's that are nested within each other to display sub menus. When each list item is clicked, it will display the child unordered list by adding the "show" class. I can't seem to figure out how to remove the "show" class once one of the "topLevel" list item components is clicked (those are the three main menu options).
Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eu1rc4ma/2/

Thanks in advance!

Tried using spans to remove the class from all child components.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="show">
          <li>
            <span class="topLevel">Services</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                1
                <ul>
                  <li>1.1</li>
                  <li>1.2</li>
                  <li>1.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                2
                <ul>
                  <li>2.1</li>
                  <li>2.2</li>
                  <li>2.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                3
                <ul>
                  <li>3.1</li>
                  <li>3.2</li>
                  <li>3.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="topLevel">Technology</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                1
                <ul>
                  <li>1.1</li>
                  <li>1.2</li>
                  <li>1.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                2
                <ul>
                  <li>2.1</li>
                  <li>2.2</li>
                  <li>2.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                3
                <ul>
                  <li>3.1</li>
                  <li>3.2</li>
                  <li>3.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="topLevel">About</span>
            <ul>
              <li>
                1
                <ul>
                  <li>1.1</li>
                  <li>1.2</li>
                  <li>1.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                2
                <ul>
                  <li>2.1</li>
                  <li>2.2</li>
                  <li>2.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                3
                <ul>
                  <li>3.1</li>
                  <li>3.2</li>
                  <li>3.3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    ul {
      display: none;
    }

    .show {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```
    let targets = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    targets.forEach(function(target) {
      target.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let subMenu = target.querySelector("ul");
        subMenu.classList.add("show");
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by checking if `ul` has `.show`

```js
let targets = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let main, sub;
targets.forEach(function(target) {
  if (target.parentElement.parentElement.tagName == "DIV") { // for mains
    target.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      let subMenu = target.querySelector("ul");
      toggleClass(subMenu);
      if (main && main != subMenu) {
        main.classList.remove("show")
      }
      main = subMenu;
    });
  } else if (target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.tagName == "DIV") {
    target.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      let subMenu = target.querySelector("ul");
      toggleClass(subMenu);
      if (sub && sub != subMenu) {
        sub.classList.remove("show")
      }
      sub = subMenu;
    });
  } else {
    target.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
});


function toggleClass(subMenu) {
  if (subMenu.className.includes('show')) {
    subMenu.classList.remove("show")
  } else {
    subMenu.classList.add("show");
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="show">
      <li>
        <span class="topLevel">Services</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            1
            <ul>
              <li>1.1</li>
              <li>1.2</li>
              <li>1.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            2
            <ul>
              <li>2.1</li>
              <li>2.2</li>
              <li>2.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            3
            <ul>
              <li>3.1</li>
              <li>3.2</li>
              <li>3.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="topLevel">Technology</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            1
            <ul>
              <li>1.1</li>
              <li>1.2</li>
              <li>1.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            2
            <ul>
              <li>2.1</li>
              <li>2.2</li>
              <li>2.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            3
            <ul>
              <li>3.1</li>
              <li>3.2</li>
              <li>3.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="topLevel">About</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            1
            <ul>
              <li>1.1</li>
              <li>1.2</li>
              <li>1.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            2
            <ul>
              <li>2.1</li>
              <li>2.2</li>
              <li>2.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            3
            <ul>
              <li>3.1</li>
              <li>3.2</li>
              <li>3.3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should've been more specific, I want everything within the first UL (the one that comes with the show class) to have the "show" class removed when either services/tech/about is clicked. Basically, if every menu was open in services and I clicked Technology then all menus in services will close and the first menu in tech will open. Sorry for not explaining well enough before. I tried to fix it with your code and didn't have any luck on my own

Comment: Also I know I could just check if the li contained "services" and then remove all "show," but I was hoping to get it working even if the innerHTML changed

Comment: @JohnFWolfe if i have understood you correctly, then you need only one menu to expand. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: That is perfect, except when you click on 1, 2, or 3 it should expand the next list. Otherwise, it is working as intended. How could we let those be expanded as well?

Comment: would be easier with jQuery, do you need that way or pure JS?

Comment: Need pure JS, I'm trying to figure this out right now but can't seem to

Comment: so, to be clear, when 1 is opened, and i click on 1, it should close 1 and open 2? right?

Comment: not sure exactly what you are after mate, i can help you if you can be a bit more clear. Did not find menu in caa.com matching to what is there here

Comment: Sorry, thanks for staying with me. When a list item is clicked it will add the "show" class to the child ul element. If a parent list item is clicked then it will remove the "show" class from the child ul element. That way if "services" is clicked then it will show the immediate child ul element. Then if one of the list items within that ul element is clicked, it will show the child ul element of that list item. If I were to then click the "technology" list item then it would act as services did earlier and only show the immediate ul element. https://outklip.com/v/-Lm7t_8TNf2gCeueFxYV

Comment: That link is a screen recording I took of caa.com, as you can see there are 3 ul elements with many list items within. Their HTML is set up the same way

Comment: @JohnFWolfe i haved edited the code, although, you might need to find a stable solution is determining the li levels other than using parentElement, this solution will work and you can tweak to your final one.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your help! Exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in order to toggle your list:
    let

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll("li");
targets.forEach(function(target) {
  target.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let subMenu = target.querySelector("ul");
    let isOpen = subMenu.classList.contains('show');
    if (!isOpen) {
      subMenu.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      subMenu.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
});
```

working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vfxtcbpd/2/